# How to reduce a computational complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity

I have this algorithm:

```
int x[100001],n,j,k,i;
int maxi=0;

for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
        bool ok=true;
        for (k=i+1; k<=j; k++) {
            if (x[i]<x[i-1]) {
                ok=false;
            }
        }
        if (ok == true) {
            if (j-i+1 > maxi) {
                maxi = j-i+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << maxi;
```

How can I reduce the complexity, which initially was obviously **`O(N^3)`** in order to make the algorithm more efficient?

Comment: A) What language is this? That should be tagged as a hint. B) This is in urgent need of proper indentation. Presentation matters here, it helps us understand your intent.

Comment: What is this algorithm supposed to do? Also I feel like this belongs in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am sorry! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: `k` is not used in the innermost loop, so you can drop the entire loop, unless the expression inside `if` is supposed to be different.

Comment: If you are not initializing `n`, be default it's 0, right? So the first exit condition `i < n` is false. Does the loop even run?

Comment: I think I must put n to be greater than 2 or 3 too.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this algorithm?

Comment: @JabariDash Only if it's a global variable. But I'm pretty sure this is supposed to be a code snippet, and that `x[...]` and `n` are assigned values before the loop runs.

Comment: @hvd That's fair. It's just a little unclear because n is being declared on the first line. But, with no initialize value

Comment: is there anything clear about this question?
1. I guess it is C, but there are many issues with the code. 2. tell us what the algorithm trying to achieve, instead of us trying to Reverse-Engineer some broken code.
3. try fixing the code.

Comment: I don't know what the algorithm does, that's the main problem. This was on my yesterday exam and I want to know what is a corect way to do that. The question is just to make the algorithm more efficient.

Comment: The algorithm looks like a non-working brute force attempt to find the length of a sequence's longest increasing subsequence by just trying all possible subsequences.

Comment: Is it wrong? I copied the entire sequence given.

Comment: dasblinkenlight already pointed out what's probably wrong about it (`k` not actually being used anywhere)

Comment: So In order to be more effiecient I must replace that useles 'for' with something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, as much as i can get from that question, this is a O(n^2) version for what i assume the algo is doing (Badly)..

removed the inner boundary loop, as it is useless.

```
int n_squared_FindLongestAscendingSubsequence(int* x, int n)
{
    int j, k, i;
    int maxi = 0;

    for (i = 1; i<n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            if (x[j]<x[j - 1]) 
            { // found the point where the seq descends
                if (j - i > maxi) // if it is longer then what we found?
                    maxi = j - i;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxi;
}
```

Another solution in O(n):

```
int n_FindLongestAscendingSubsequence(int* x, int n)
{
    int maxi = 0;
    int anchor = 0; // will save the index from where it ascends
    int prev = -2 ^ 31;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] < x[i-1])
        { // found a point where the seq descends
            if (i - anchor > maxi) // if it is longer then what we found?
                maxi = i - x[i];
            anchor = i; // no point going to 'anchor+1', because all seq will be shorter untill 'i'.
        }
    }
    return maxi;
}
```

Comment: it can be done in O(n) too, but the question didn't say requirements :)